# Accordion Image Does Not Change When Clicking Link In Another Accordion

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page which has multiple accordions on.  Each accordion has a chevron-down image displayed at the end and when you click on the title to expand the accordion, the image changes to a chevron-up image.

These work perfectly but if I have a link in on accordion that references another accordion, the referenced accordion expands as expected BUT my image doesn't change as the user didn't click on the newly expanded accordion.

How do I do this.

My `<a>` is

```
<p><a class="collapsed" href="#SubTitle2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">Test</a></p>
```

Below is a screenshot of when I have clicked the link in the first accordion and it expands my second accordion.

[image]

The image for 'Heading 2' should be the 'Chevron-Up' as it is for the 'Heading 1'

This is done via my CSS as shown below

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle-inforcentre:after
     font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
     content:"\e113";
     position: absolute;
     right: 2.5em;

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle-inforcentre.collapsed:after
     content:"\e114";
```

My complete HTML is

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" class="accordion-toggle-inforcentre collapsed">Heading 1</a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Paragraph 1</p>
                <p>Paragraph 2</p>
                <p><a class="collapsed" href="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">Paragraph 3 - opens accordion below</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" class="accordion-toggle-inforcentre collapsed">Heading 2</a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Paragraph 1</p>
                <p>Paragraph 2</p>
                <p>Paragraph 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you change the chevron? JQuery?

Comment: @StevenWeb, please see my CSS which does the image change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a local project and used bootstrap 3 based on the sample [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) I did:

```
    .panel-heading a:after {
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        content: "\e113";
        position: absolute;
        right: 1.5em;
    }

    .panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
        content: "\e114";
    }
```

and it worked well!

Update:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/86qrku9h/)

OK now I understand: The problem is that the collapsed class will only change on click on the corresponding bootstrap element. So you have to manipulate the class with jQuery.

You can do this like:

```
    $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        $(e.target).closest('.panel-default')
            .find('.panel-heading a')
            .removeClass('collapsed');
    });
```

I made this snipped based on my sample. I just added a custom link in the first container like:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                content A
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/86qrku9h/4/)

UPDATE:

Add the class collapsed to the closes accordion parts like:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" 
   class="collapsed" 
   data-parent="#accordion" 
   href="#collapseTwo">
   Collapsible Group Item #2
</a>
```

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/86qrku9h/11/)

Comment: Thanks for the update but I think you have misunderstood what my issue is.  My accordion image works fine when I click on the heading, my issue is that if I click a link in one that expands another, then the image does not change

Comment: thanks for the update but I cant seem to get it to work with my HTML.  I have added my updated CSS and also my HTML, what am I doing wrong as if I paste you stuff from your fiddle it works

Comment: @murday1983 added a new answer with a sample

Comment: there is a problem with your snippet/demo, when I first open it they all display as 'a' then when I click the link the first 2 display as 'b' and the last one as 'a' then they work fine.  When I first enter the page, only the first one should be 'a', the other 2 should be 'b'

Comment: sorry to be a pain, I was looking at the wrong demo.  all appears to be working as expected.  Thanks for all you help

Comment: ^^ But you where right. There was a problem in my sample. I made a update anyway! You are welcome! @murday1983

Comment: This is working great now but I have a small problem, a couple of my links in one accordion reference another accordion on another page.  I have the function that auto expands it and its working but the image does not change.  I have all the code/Jquery you supplied but it still doesn't change it.  I suspect it maybe due to it being on another page not sure, is there a way to do this so the imagry works as it does in your demo's?

Answer (score 1):

In my sample the accordion with the nested link will close after i trigger the open event for the external accordion part and you have to close it through clicking on the corresponding link.

In your sample it stays open. So the user is able to close the external accordion through the external link.

You Problem is now that you have to trigger once again the event (close in this case) with jquery like:

```
    $('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        $(e.target).closest('.panel-default')
            .find('.panel-heading a')
            .addClass('collapsed');
    });
```

Here's a sample with your html: http://jsfiddle.net/86qrku9h/6/

Hope that helps out :)